# Inverse of indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Taken from *Measure, Integral and Probability* by *Capinski and Kopp*.

I am trying to figure out how to figure out inverse of indicator functions. So let's use this example I found.

Given a set $A$ with its indicator function (where $\mathbf1 _{A}$ is Lebesgue measurable),

\begin{equation}
 \mathbf1 _{A}(x)=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $x\in A$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

**Why is its inverse (pre-image) this?**

\begin{equation}
 \mathbf1 ^-_{A}((a, \infty))=\begin{cases}
    \mathbb{R}, & \text{if $a<0$}.\\
     A,         & \text{if $0 \leq a < 1$}.\\    
    \emptyset , & \text{if $a \geq 1$}..
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

**My thoughts (I may be completely wrong, please correct me):**

So first and foremost, think of $x = (a, \infty)$. 
Secondly given $\mathbf1 _{A}$, its range is *exactly {0,1}* and therefore, when thinking of its inverse, I should consider that interval.

So let's consider when a is within the interval, then I will always get back my set $A$.

But, how do I get the other two cases then?

I was trying to learn from this example but it wasn't apparent for me.
[Inverse image sets for indicator functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2793243/inverse-image-sets-for-indicator-functions)

I understand this is a trivial matter but please be patient with me.

Comment: You can do better for the range. The range is *exactly* the 2 point set $\{0,1\}$

Comment: If $a$ is outside the interval, then $\{0,1\} \subset (-a,\infty)$, thus the entire range of your function is inside $(-a, \infty)$. What does this say about the preimage?

Comment: Am I right to say since my entire function is now within $(-a, \infty)$, hence its pre-image includes all Reals. And similarly, if I'm only including "half the range" for $a\geq 1$, thus the pre-image which doesn't lie in the interval is $\emptyset$ .

Comment: You have $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}((a,\infty))=A$ for $0\leq a<1$ but $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}((1,\infty))=\emptyset$ since $1\notin (1,\infty)$  I think. Is this a typo in the book You are citing?

Comment: @PeterMelech You are right, I made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @mathnoob You are welcome and of course if $a<0$ the whole range of the indicator function is in that interval, i.e. $\{0,1\}=im(\mathbb{1}_A)\subset (a,\infty)$ and thus the preimage is the whole set the indicator function is defined on, namely $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ah. Yeah that helps. Thanks for clarifying this out. Makes a lot of sense now especially after fixing that inequality mistake. I had trouble accepting one side of the argument and then the other before because of the inequality but failed to notice it as cause of the problem directly. Many thanks to both PeterMelech and rubikscube09 for your time and attention.